# AngularJS Home Page - Localization Example

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am studying the Localization example at the bottom of AngularJS home page.

I am looking at the source of the page and try to do exactly what the demo shows me.

However, I can't seem to fire up the demo code. The lines that confused me the most are:

```
   <span class="pull-right" 
    js-fiddle="tabs.html components.js beers.js" module="components"> ...
   <div app-run="tabs.html" module="components-us" class="well"> ...
```

Because I don't recognise `app-run` or `js-fiddle` to be AngularJS syntax (or is it?). Anyway, the demo  app doesn't fire up. Could you please help me take a look?

Here is the code I COPY & PASTE from AngularJS home page and put in index.html: (change the header base and libraries to your directory accordingly)

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- ************IMPORTANT !! change this to your directory************ -->
        <base href='http://localhost/angularjs/localization/' />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
        <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class=" row example">
        <div class="span1 app-source" app-source="tabs.html components.js beers.js" annotate="tabs.annotation" module="components"></div>
        <div class="span4">
            <span hint></span>
            <span class="pull-right" js-fiddle="tabs.html components.js beers.js" module="components"></span>
            <div class="tabs-spacer"></div>
            <h4>Locale: {{ 'US' }}</h4>
            <div app-run="tabs.html" module="components-us" class="well"></div>
            <div class="tabs-spacer"></div>
            <h4>Locale: {{ 'SK' }}</h4>
            <div app-run="tabs.html" module="components-sk" class="well"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        angular.module('components-us', ['components', 'ngLocal.us']);
        angular.module('components-sk', ['components', 'ngLocal.sk']);
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="tabs.html">
        <tabs>
            <pane title="Localization">
                Date: {{ '2012-04-01' | date:'fullDate' }} <br>
                Currency: {{ 123456 | currency }} <br>
                Number: {{ 98765.4321 | number }} <br>
            </pane>
            <pane title="Pluralization">
                <div ng-controller="BeerCounter">
                    <div ng-repeat="beerCount in beers">
                        <ng-pluralize count="beerCount" when="beerForms"></ng-pluralize>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </pane>
        </tabs>
    </script>

    <script id="beers.js">
        function BeerCounter($scope, $locale) {
            $scope.beers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
            if ($locale.id == 'en-us') {
                $scope.beerForms = {
                    0: 'no beers',
                    one: '{} beer',
                    other: '{} beers'
                };
            } else {
                $scope.beerForms = {
                    0: 'žiadne pivo',
                    one: '{} pivo',
                    few: '{} pivá',
                    other: '{} pív'
                };
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script id="components.js">
        angular.module('components', []).
                directive('tabs', function() {
                    return {
                        restrict: 'E',
                        transclude: true,
                        scope: {},
                        controller: function($scope, $element) {
                            var panes = $scope.panes = [];

                            $scope.select = function(pane) {
                                angular.forEach(panes, function(pane) {
                                    pane.selected = false;
                                });
                                pane.selected = true;
                            }

                            this.addPane = function(pane) {
                                if (panes.length == 0) $scope.select(pane);
                                panes.push(pane);
                            }
                        },
                        template:
                                '<div class="tabbable">' +
                                        '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">' +
                                        '<li ng-repeat="pane in panes" ng-class="{active:pane.selected}">'+
                                        '<a href="" ng-click="select(pane)">{{pane.title}}</a>' +
                                        '</li>' +
                                        '</ul>' +
                                        '<div class="tab-content" ng-transclude></div>' +
                                        '</div>',
                        replace: true
                    };
                }).
                directive('pane', function() {
                    return {
                        require: '^tabs',
                        restrict: 'E',
                        transclude: true,
                        scope: { title: '@' },
                        link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
                            tabsCtrl.addPane(scope);
                        },
                        template:
                                '<div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{active: selected}" ng-transclude>' +
                                        '</div>',
                        replace: true
                    };
                })
    </script>

   </body>
</html>
```

Also, where are `app-run` and `js-fiddle` from? I can't figure out if they are features belong to AngularJS or what.

Comment: Are you trying to understand how they embedded this example onto the home page, or do you just want to look at the localization example?  If the latter, just click the blue "Edit Me" button and you'll get a working example in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[app-run](https://github.com/angular/angularjs.org/blob/master/js/homepage.js#L100) and [js-fiddle](https://github.com/angular/angularjs.org/blob/master/js/homepage.js#L240) are custom Angular directives -- i.e., directives they wrote to help run the AngularJS home page (hence the reason they are in the file aptly named homepage.js).

Here is a [working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/C6iolSmoBmspa4xOAXgC?p=preview) of the demo.